# Finding the Covariance of a portfolio given the weights of two assets, with their probability and return % for each asset.

Tags: probability, covariance, ratio

I am given the details below:

The following Table reflects data relating to two assets X and Y, which are present in a portfolio in the ratio 60:40

```
Probability | Return on X(%) | Return on Y(%)

    0.2            -10            -1.40
    0.4             25            -2.25
    0.3             25            -2.00 
    0.1             10            -10.00
```

I had to state what type of portfolio it was and the answer was that it was a nil covariance portfolio.

The calculation to prove this was written as:
Cov = (0.2x-25x1.38)+(0.4x10x0.53)+(0.3x5x0.78)+(0.1x-5x-7.22)=0

The first value in the bracket is the probability, and the third is the return of Y minus the expected return of Y but I think the middle number is incorrect.

Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1):

The mean

$E[X] = \Sigma P(Scenario_1) X_i\\
E[Y] = \Sigma P(Scenario_1) Y_i$

$\bar X = (0.2)(-10) + (0.4)(25) + (0.3)(25) + (0.1)(10) = 16.5\\
\bar Y = -2.78$

Each asset has a variance.

$\sigma_X^2 = \Sigma P(Scenario_i)(X_i - \bar X)\\
\sigma_Y^2 = \Sigma P(Scenario_i)(Y_i - \bar Y)$

$\sigma_X^2 = 195.3\\
\sigma_Y^2 = 5.9$

There is a covariance between the two assets.

$\text{Cov}_{X,Y}=\Sigma P(Scenario_i)(X_i - \bar X)(Y_i - \bar Y)$

$\text{Cov}_{X,Y} = 1.17$

And the portfolio with weights $\omega_x, \omega_y$ will have a variance.

$\sigma_P^2=\omega_X^2\sigma_X^2 + \omega_Y^2\sigma_Y^2 + 2\omega_X\omega_Y\text{Cov}_{X,Y} = 71.8$

And expected return $E[R] = 8.8$

Comment: Hi, yes I used the formula you mentioned for the Covariance but the answer I was calculating was: 
Mean X = 12.5
Mean Y = -3.91
Using these values, that would mean Covariance would equal 3.375/4 = 0.84375?
I am unsure how the value would be 0, am I wrong or perhaps the answer is incorrect?

Comment: Covariance doesn't enter into the mean calculation.  $E[\omega_XX + \omega_YY] = \omega_XE[X] + \omega_YE[Y]$

Comment: Can you explain? I'm not sure how to get the right symbol for it, but is that not what 'X bar' and 'Y bar' is? The mean?

Comment: $\bar X$ is the mean of $X$ which is $E[X].$  When I took a look at your calculated values for $\bar X,\bar Y$ it looks like you are not including the scenario weights in your calculation,  each scenario should not be equally weighted.  I have included the values that I have calculated for each of these statistics, in case that helps.

Comment: Yes, I think the answer they have given is incorrect, I have tried different calculations each time and could not get the same values as the answer given in my sample question, the covariance should not be 0. Thank you for your time!